# Is there a way to render points in XTK that scale with zoom?

Tags: xtk

Parts of a brain have been rendered with XTK [nightly] at: http://mindboggle.info/. however, if you zoom out, you can see that the red points/cubes don't scale.

Answer (score 0):

Since XTK uses the gl_PointSize in the shaders to set the pointSize if specified with
X.object.setPointSize(size), the camera position (from zooming etc.) is not used to re-calculate the point size on interaction.

What you could do is the following as shown in the lesson 09:

Code: https://github.com/xtk/lessons/blob/master/09/index.html

Here is the live version: http://lessons.goxtk.com/09/

Note that the loading takes a little longer then if just rendering as points since the sphere meshes are actually created using CSG.

This will not work for the lineWidth so :)